# Deleting expired IP-Addresses

Tags: dhcpd

I am testing Ubuntu 12.10 DHCP server, it's working fine, but I need to delete all IP-Addresses which have been give from the DHCP-pool, as I would like to start fresh before I clone the server to another HD.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Madona33

Comment: Could you please check  /var/lib/dhcp3/dhcpd.leases ?

Answer (score 0):

stop your server and delete file `/var/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases`